# Facebook grap APU $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken() with no value

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm stuck...
Everything looks correct but it does not work. Tried with a debug access token from my app at facebook developer and it works great so its not an issue with the resto of the code.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
/******Improting Facebook API Files**************/
require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';
require_once 'credentials.php';
/******Facebook API Connection With My APP**************/
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => $appid,
'app_secret' => $appsecret,
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3'
]);

/******Initializing The Login**************/
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile']; // optional

#echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$incommingurl.'");</script>';
#echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$permissions.'");</script>';
#var_dump($permissions);
#var_dump($helper);

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($incommingurl, $permissions);


/******Printing The Login URL**************/
echo'<a href="' . $loginUrl . '" class="facebookLoginButton" title="Login With Facebook">Sign in with Facebook</a>';
?>
```

**token.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
/******Improting Facebook API Files**************/
require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';
require_once 'credentials.php';

/******Facebook API Connection With My APP**************/
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                    'app_id' => $appid,
                    'app_secret' => $appsecret,
                    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3'
                    ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

/******Getting Token From Facebook**************/


var_dump($helper);

try {
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("1235")</script>';
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
var_dump($accessToken);

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

/******Storing Token In Sessions For Further Use**************/
if (isset($accessToken)) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = (string) $accessToken;
  echo $_SESSION['token'];
  header('location: collectUserData.php');
}
else{
  //echo "err";
  header('location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Setting $accesstoken with a valid token the code works so im not getting the access token. I can dump $helper and the result is:

```
object(Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper)#7 (4) { ["oAuth2Client":protected]=> object(Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client)#8 (4) { ["app":protected]=> object(Facebook\FacebookApp)#3 (2) { ["id":protected]=> string(15) "xxxxxxxxxxxx" ["secret":protected]=> string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" } ["client":protected]=> object(Facebook\FacebookClient)#4 (2) { ["enableBetaMode":protected]=> bool(false) ["httpClientHandler":protected]=> object(Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient)#5 (4) { ["curlErrorMessage":protected]=> string(0) "" ["curlErrorCode":protected]=> int(0) ["rawResponse":protected]=> NULL ["facebookCurl":protected]=> object(Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl)#6 (1) { ["curl":protected]=> NULL } } } ["graphVersion":protected]=> string(4) "v2.3" ["lastRequest":protected]=> NULL } ["urlDetectionHandler":protected]=> object(Facebook\Url\FacebookUrlDetectionHandler)#10 (0) { } ["persistentDataHandler":protected]=> object(Facebook\PersistentData\FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler)#9 (1) { ["sessionPrefix":protected]=> string(6) "FBRLH_" } ["pseudoRandomStringGenerator":protected]=> object(Facebook\PseudoRandomString\McryptPseudoRandomStringGenerator)#11 (0) { } }
```

But no result on  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    var_dump($accessToken);

Can anyone please help?

Best regards and a happy new year :-)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/958

petertoth0507 commented on 25 May 2018

The solution is in the following:
In the old times the getAccessToken function worked without parameter:
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

In current time you must set the callback URL, example:
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('https://www.classfund.hu/index.php?r=site/fblogincallback');

In parallel you must set the same parameter at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ page at your application property, Products->Settings->Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field.

When I set the above mentioned params the authentication operating properly again....